# How can I keep SSH connection alive?

Tags: ssh, connection, ubuntu-10.04, ssh-tunnel

I use Ubuntu 14.04 on my server and I've added these lines into `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`: *(as it's mentioned [here](https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/))*

```
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 2
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

Now my server is broken `:(`. I cannot connect to it through neither regular SSH connection nor tunneling:

Regular SSH Connection:

[image]

Tunneling To MySQL For Accessing Databases On The Server

[image]

I really have valuable data into server's databases without any backup. Any idea?

Comment: Where is your machine hosted?

Comment: What? Do you what to know the place of my physical server? I guess it should be in Germany.

Comment: I meant who is it hosted with and what type of hosting do you have?  With that information you can start to find out options for getting access to your server.  Based on your ip address it looks like you are using hetzner?

Comment: What's the real question you expect to be answered? Is it "how do I use AliveInterval", or "how do I fix my broken server"?

Comment: @grawity *"how do I use AliveInterval"*. Since my problem fixed. *(using VNC)*